# Get rid of piezo buzzer base (annoying) buzzing sound when LED's connected to same power source (+5v) are turned on

Tags: transistors, bjt, piezo-buzzer

I have a circuit in which a piezo buzzer is connected to a stm32f303 mcu like so (the DAC pin goes straight into the MCU):
[image]

I also have some WS2812B mini LEDs that are connected to a +5v plane (which the buzzer is also connected to). However, whenever the leds are on, the buzzer emits a faint sound (which is kind of annoying).

I did some tests with a voltmeter. When the LEDs are turned on, the piezo buzzer is only getting around 3.5V whereas with the LEDs turned off, the piezo buzzer is getting around 4.8V. I'm not sure how this would result in a slight buzzing noise, but thought I'd share it.

I also tried adding a capacitor from +5v to GND in case it would help filter some electrical noise but it didn't really seem to do anything.

Can somebody help me debug why this is happening and how to stop it?

Comment: Hi Bob.  Please add in more of the schematic.  specifically the LEDs and how they connect back to the mcu.

Comment: Decoupling capacitors?  Actual NPN part number.  Buzzer part number.

Comment: Which capacitor? You can try more capacitors! (Or an LC filter - at some point combining L and C gets better bang for the buck than piling on more C)